# Run sub procedure in excel after values passed from MS Access record

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database which successfully passes the values in my current record to an Excel sheet. To calculate my Excel sheet I then need to call a subroutine.

I think my problem is the order in which things are happening.

I have tried to call the routine (within Excel) from the `MyWorkbook` with the following code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
On Error Resume Next

With Application
    .DisplayFullScreen = True
    .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = True
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Call Rategenerator    
Sheets("home").Select
End Sub
```

The routine `Rategenerator` is, I think, being called before the values from the Access record are populating the designated cells in my sheet "home."

Is there a way to force the sub routine `Rategenerator` to execute after the values are populated on the sheet?

The code from the current Access record to populate the Excel sheet looks like this:

```
Dim objXLApp  As Object
Dim objXLBook  As Object
Dim r As Object


'check whether Excel is open before opening another copy.
Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("e:\!!!Access SHare Folder\Ogden v7.1.1.5        final.xls")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True

'Specify Sheet
With objXLBook.Sheets("home")
.unProtect Password:="xxxxxxxx"

.Cells(15, 6).Value = Me.DateofAcc
.Cells(16, 6).Value = Me.DOB
.Cells(17, 6).Value = Me.todaysDate
.Cells(18, 6).Value = Me.Gender
.Cells(19, 6).Value = Me.RetireAge
.Cells(22, 6).Value = Me.DeferredAge
.Cells(28, 6).Value = Me.ContEmpPre
.Cells(29, 6).Value = Me.ContDisPre
.Cells(30, 6).Value = Me.txtContOveridePre  'taken from the txtbox not the checkbox
.Cells(31, 6).Value = Me.ContOverideValPre
.Cells(28, 7).Value = Me.ContEmpPost
.Cells(29, 7).Value = Me.ContDisPost
.Cells(30, 7).Value = Me.txtContOveridePost 'taken from the txtbox not the checkbox
.Cells(31, 7).Value = Me.ContOverideValPost
End With

With objXLBook.Sheets("LOETblCalx")

.Cells(19, 17).Value = Me.SalaryNet1
.Cells(20, 17).Value = Me.Residual1
End With

''Tidy up
Set objXLBook = Nothing
Set objXLApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

As I say all the field values from the Access record populate without issue. Parts of the Excel workbook which do not rely on the sub routine auto calculate as expected with Auto calculation in the workbook turned on.

Its just the triggering of the sub routine **after** the cells have been populated which is causing me some difficulty.

Eventually I want to try and get the calculated results back into some additional fields in the Access record but having never attempted anything like that before I'm careful not to get ahead of myself.

Thanks for looking

Comment: How are you populating the values from Access?

Comment: Since rate generation is the last task to be performed, I would have thought Workbook Close was the appropriate event.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment; perhaps you did not understand mine.  What I meant was: try replacing `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()` with `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` so the routine is called at the end rather than the beginning.

Comment: Hi, not sure that's going to work for me as once the stored Access field values are populated in Excel I am trying to present the users with the final calculated cell values and not those from the workbooks last saved state.

Comment: Isn't Access closing the workbook?  I have not tested this from Access but if an Excel macro opens and closes a workbook with a Workbook_BeforeClose routine, that routine is called.

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear. The dozen or so field values are just the jumping off point for the users scenario creation tasks in the Excel Workbook. In most case, but not all, they will have to trigger the code to update any changes they may have made for the default values arriving from Access. However if the scenario result in Excel is based on the default values arriving from Access then it would be 'tidier' if they didn't need to execute the code manually from a command button in Excel. A small thing I know but for something which on the face of it would seem pretty straight forward..

Comment: You added your latest comment just I have finished reading your Access code and had noticed that you are not closing the workbook but leaving it open for the user.  So sorry, the before close event is no use.  I think if you can get mattboy's suggestion to work, that would be the best.  A less satisfactory approach would be to copy Rategenerator into Access.  Another possibility is a worksheet change event against a hidden worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Workbook_Activate(), try running the Excel macro directly from your Access code after it has finished populating. This would be done by putting code similar to this at the end (before the tidy up part) of your Access macro: `objXLBook.Run "Rategenerator"`

I'm not sure if that exact piece of code will work for you, but see [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-an-excel-macro-from-access-or-another-excel-workbook/) for more details on how to do it.

Comment: This sounds like it is just what I'm after but having tries I get a Error 438 Object does not support this property of method? I've read the linked article and it makes sense to me so I'm puzzled why it is throwing a wobbly in my project.

Comment: I think the **.Run** property belongs to **Application** rather than **WorkBook**, are you able to try **objXLApp.Run "Rategenerator"**?

Comment: Something is definitely happening there but the Excel sheet simply locks up and is completely unresponsive. Isn't even redrawing? Run the same macro from with VBA window in Excel and all is fine. Very odd

Comment: @user1726291 There's an option under the general options tab called **Ignore other applications** in 2003 anyway but may vary in different versions, try **un-checking** this to see if it makes a difference.